# GIT merge and rebase workflow confirmation?

Tags: git, version-control

I have read a few others' questions regarding merge VS rebase, what to use and when, but I still have some questions for regular GIT users.  Firstly, let me post what I understand to be good GIT practice:

1. Create new branch B from existing branch A
2. Add/commit changes on branch B
3. Rebase updates from branch A
4. Merge changes from branch B onto branch A"

From what I understand so far, the workflow above works best when using a heirarchical branching model (i.e. A = master branch, and B = experimental branch for working on a new feature).  In short, it's good to rebase down the tree, and merge back up to the master.  Am I correct in thinking this?

Now, if working with other developers who might be committing/merging changes to A (master branch), I would assume it's best for me to repeat steps 2 and 3 as often as I like to ensure that my work on branch B does not conflict with anything other users have been committing to branch A.  If there are any conflicts, using rebase on branch 2 would reapply my commits and allow me to work out these conflicts BEFORE merging back up to branch A.  Am I correct in my understanding?

Lastly, here's my main question: If I am not working with any other developers, and I am not touching branch A until I've finished my new feature in branch B, can I then skip the rebase (step 3), and just merge branch B into the master branch A?  I guess it still doesn't hurt to do a rebase first, but unnecessary if I know that branch A hasn't been touched since creating branch B.  Am I correct in my understanding?

PS. I'd like to thank you guys in advance for any guidance you can give me!  I'm new to GIT, and never used a SCM system before using GIT.

Thank you,
Jesse Leite
http://www.aurorafxstudios.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not a good idea to over-use rebase. I started out that way but have done nothing but merges and resets. Take a look at [my workflow](http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/). It is based on [nvie's](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

In short, you want to be organized with your work. Making branch A the basis for branch B ties them together. This can be a bad thing if something in A is bad, it may not be trivial to "undo" it.

Comment: Using all merges will create unnecessary commits, however. If you are working in a feature branch stemming from your main branch, rebasing keeps your history clean. If you are merging into a release branch, though, then I'd agree that using `merge` + `--no-ff` is a much better way to go, since you'll have a new commit to tag.

Comment: "clean history" is overrated. You can erase all your intermediate commits from your feature branches by reseting and merging again. Or, you can fake an octopus merge if you want all features to come to one commit by manually adding the sha_1s to MERGE_HEAD and commit. Use the set notation for log or gitk along with `--no-merges` and `git branch --contains` to see where you're at. Pretty lines in gitk are not the end goal of software development.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Doesn't rebase essentially reset the current branch by replacing it with up-to-date code from your master branch, then re-apply your branch specific commits?  I skimmed over your article, but this GIT stuff is so new to me that half of the terms are going over my head :(  I will spend some time re-reading your article though.  Looks like you make some good points.  Maybe I'll go and read nvie's too.  How does yours differ from nvie's?

Comment: every feature for a release starts from the same point. nvie's process allows branches to start from points were some other features were already integrated. This couples them, my process doesn't.

Comment: I just read through both nvie's workflow post and your workflow.  I understand nvie's workflow, but I still have a few questions about yours.  By "every feature for a release starts from the same point", do you mean that commits are not allowed on the develop branch (as per nvie's terminology) between version releases?  This means all feature branches are essentially forced to start from the last released version, correct?

Comment: Also, my second question is: when a feature branch is complete, is it allowed to merge back into the develop branch immediately upon completion?  I gather from your workflow that new features are to stay on their respective branches, and when ready for next release, the developer in charge of release can pick and choose which features he/she wants to include in the final release.  Would he/she be grabbing those features from the develop branch, or from the feature branches themselves?  PS. I'd love to see you post a visual model-diagram like nvie's; it really helped me understand his workflow.

Comment: Lastly, my third question is about rebase once again. You mentioned using mostly merge and reset. Is there ever any situation where you have found rebase to be useful?

Comment: @AdamDymitruk Your workarounds to avoid `rebase` but still achieve "clean history" feel really hacky - can you give a solid reason why rebasing should not be used, and yet erasing all intermediate commits before merging is a better option? The `rebase` feature exists for a reason. According to your blog, the primary objective is to have each branch live as separately as possible - but to what purpose? Same branches don't need to strive live alone - they are feature branches dependent on the main development branch. Can you elaborate on your thought process?

Comment: There are times when rebasing is needed - like you realize you should have refactored before starting the iteration. This should be the exception. If you just released and realize that there is problem with feature 3, it's easy to make a new release candidate by merging all the features again while excluding feature 3. If you're rebasing, you are adding a lot of complexity. The other issue with rebasing, is that you may get into a situation where you're resolving conflicts for each rebased commit. This really can slow you down. Having done it both ways, I much prefer my approach over rebase.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is sound. If nothing's touched A, then your rebase would be a no-op. The nice thing with A not changing is that you know there'll be no conflicts!